# Static Factory Method query

Tags: java, constructor

prob 1 : What is this code its a constructor or a method or else?
prob 2 : How is this return statement working (both)?
Can anyone please explain...

```
public class RandomIntGenerator 
{
    private final int min;
    private final int max;

    private RandomIntGenerator(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public static RandomIntGenerator between(int max, int min)    //Prob 1    
    {
        return new RandomIntGenerator(min, max);                  //Prob 2    
    }

    public static RandomIntGenerator biggerThan(int min) {
        return new RandomIntGenerator(min, Integer.MAX_VALUE);      //Prob 2    
    }

    public static RandomIntGenerator smallerThan(int max) {
        return new RandomIntGenerator(Integer.MIN_VALUE, max);
    }

    public int next() {...}      //its just a method
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically they are methods which return new instances of the `RandomIntGenerator` class. Once you have those you can use the `next()` method to get random numbers.

```
RandomIntGenerator generator = RandomIntGenerator.between(5, 10);
int a = generator.next(); //a is now a "random" number between 5 and 10.
```

If the constructor was public, you could replace the first line with the line below, as they have the same effect.

```
RandomIntGenerator generator = new RandomIntGenerator(5, 10);
```

Comment: So these are used instead of constructor? Its written that this is alternate option to use constructor with same name and signature.

Comment: Well it would be an alternate option, however the constructor is private so you can't really access it outside the `RandomIntGenerator` class. If you want, you can get rid of those methods and change the constructor's `private` modifier to `public`. Or you can have both, whatever you like.

Comment: no it can not be its the Static Factory Method like singleton where we make constructor private. If we want to declare multiple constructor with same name and signature. How it is calling that private constructor.

Comment: What do you mean by how is it calling that private constructor? The static methods are in the same class, so they have access to the constructor. They call it to create a new object and return it as shown in the example above.

Comment: May be i had to read it again. I am still confused. Anyway thanks.